# How to add column in the c++ base on N input

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int num1;
  std::string u = "";
  cout << "Enter number ";
  cin >> num1;
  
  for (int x = 1; x <= num1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= num1; y++) {
      u = u + ((x-1) * num1 + y + "");
    }
    cout << u << "";
  }
}
```

How can I add a column using a `for` loop?

My example problem if the user input 3 the output becomes

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

my error is if I run this code in cpp.sh the error is Enter number 3
the answer is this.

```
;@;@;@;@;@;@;@;@;@@
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm obviously not going to solve the problem but I'm going to help you to get help in the future: Name your variables so that what you say in writing is reflected in your code.
Cheers!

Comment: `for (int x = 1; x <= num1; x++)` - in this you do `[1, x]`. All indices are zero-based in C++, so you should be doing: `[0, x)`.. - so: `for (int x = 0; x < num1; ++x)`

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting appending a number to `std::string`. A `int` can not be appended to `std::string`. You need to convert the number to `std::string` before concatenating. I believe `std::to_string()` in `<string>` would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1;
    std::string u = "";
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num1;

    for (int x = 1; x <= num1; x++) {
        u.clear();  // clear string
        for (int y = 1; y <= num1; y++) {
            u = u + std::to_string((x - 1) * num1 + y) + " ";  // append string-converted number
        }
        cout << u << endl;  // print new line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, `(x-1) * num1 + y + ""` does not create a string with a number in it. If we look at `3 + ""`, that is interpreted as asking to skip the first 3 characters in "". Which is invalid, and causes you to see these random characters.

Instead, to append a number to a string do `u = u + std::to_string((x-1) * num1 + y)`.